# NullPointerException on set label text

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Whenever I try to set the text of a label from a different ViewController on a storyboard, i get a NullPointerException:
`System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` in the line `UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");`

Both of the view controllers are using the same class.
This is my code:

> ```
>    async partial void LoginBtn_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
>    {
>        loadingIndicator.StartAnimating();
>        var uname = username.Text;
>        var pwd = password.Text;
>        Uri loginUri = new Uri($"http://<loginapi>:8080/api/login?user={uname}&pwd={pwd}");
>        WebClient c = new WebClient();
>        string[] userinfo = parseJsonToArray(await c.DownloadStringTaskAsync(loginUri));
>        welcomeLabel.Text = "Welcome, " + userinfo[0];  //index 0 of userinfo contains the user's full name.
>        loadingIndicator.StopAnimating();
>        PerformSegue("loggedInSegue", this);
>    }
> ```

I have verified that it is getting the correct information by logging it to the console, and everything else works perfectly fine if I comment out the welcomeLabel.Text part.

Comment: Are you sure that `userinfo` has data?

Comment: @Hackerman, yes I have confirmed that by printing the data to the console.

Comment: where is "welcomeLabel" defined?

Comment: "welcomeLabel" is defined in the ViewController.designer.cs class autogenerated by the Xamarin Designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable all exception in your Visual Studio or Xamarin Studio so that you can break at line contain the null reference. Check this to enable all exceptions 
http://www.stefandevo.com/2015/12/20/xamarin-studio-tip-break-on-all-exceptions/

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to pinpoint the problem here and fix it.